# Objective-c custom indicator lock shared instance

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, singleton, block, objective-c-blocks

I have made a custom indicator in which I can run code through a block and show an indicator while the code is running.

After the code is done I call a second success block and hide/remove the indicator.

Because I dont't want to instantiate every indicator in the class where I want to use them, the indicator object is a singleton.

**Workflow:**

1. Create indicator
2. Show indicator
3. Run code block
4. Run success block
5. Hide indicator
6. Remove from superview
7. Nullify shared instance

The problem occurs when I use two indicators after each other (**example:** after login, refresh data).

When the second indicator is shown, the hide method is called on the first instance. And during the second indicator the indicator view is removed from the superview.

I have no experience with managing my own thread locks but I thought solving the problem by using `@synchronized(self)` but it seems it has no effect?

```
+ (Indicator *)create
{
    if (!sharedIndicator)
    {
        sharedIndicator = [[Indicator alloc] initWithNibName:@"Indicator" bundle:nil];
    }

    return sharedIndicator;
}

+ (Indicator *)createWithDelegate:(id <IndicatorDelegate>)delegate 
                             message:(NSString *)message 
                              inView:(UIView *)parentView
{
    Indicator *indicator = [Indicator create];
    [indicator setDelegate:delegate];
    [indicator setMessage:message];
    [indicator setParentView:parentView];

    return indicator;
}

+ (void)showInView:(UIView *)view 
       withMessage:(NSString *)message 
           execute:(BOOL (^)(void))executeBlock 
          complete:(void (^)(BOOL success))completed
{
    Indicator *indicator = [Indicator createWithDelegate:nil message:message inView:view];

    [indicator show];

    __block BOOL success = NO;

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue( DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^
    {    
        success = executeBlock();

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^
        {
            completed(success);

            [indicator hide];
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: your variable `success` should be declared inside the first block, as a normal (not `__block`) variable

Answer (score 0):

Each time you show the indicator you get the same View, since its linked with the sharedInstance.